Boot iso from android Data partition
I want to install Ubuntu, but my device does not have any ports. It is a x86 Android tablet (Lenovo Yoga tablet 2), It has 16GB of SSD and an Intel Atom (baytrail?) Z3745 processor.
Usually to install Ubuntu I could just boot from a USB, but this device does not have the ports. OTG is not enabled unless a kernel is first loaded. TWRP is installed as recovery with a minimal Linux shell.
Here is where I need help:
What format is the Data partition of Android (Lollipop) in? is it FAT32, EXT4 or another form? Could it be read by Grub?
How do I install/run parted/gdisk/any disk utility in the linux shell environment? I do have the tar.xz files. Of course there is no apt or etcetera. I read a guide about using parted but the files provided were for normal arm CPU, not a "desktop" amd64 intel CPU.
How do I boot an ISO from that partition using Grub bootloader?
Thanks.
